# How to send many request using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to send many requests using node.js?

I wrote this script, but.. console return has error:
ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED

My code

```
const request = require('request');


const headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cookie": "intro=1; PHPSESSID=cv2tniglt2v0fouov6jrjmblo6; chash=3373872b06; hs3=337; user_id=8464919; mchar_id=1107988; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.1270081288.1509529196; _gid=GA1.2.637535937.1509529196",
    "Host": "www.margonem.pl",
    "Referer": "https://www.margonem.pl/?task=profile&id=3727144",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": 1,
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/48.0.2685.52"
};

const options = {
    url: "https://www.margonem.pl/?task=profile&id=3727144",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
};

setInterval(() => {

request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(error);
 });
});
```

Who help me, and replace this script to send many request? 
I want tamp more views u know what i mean

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` would suggest a problem with the destination server, if you are sending lots of these requests then you'll probably find your being blocked...

Answer (score 0):

What you currently do is a Denial-Of-Service (DOS) Attack. If you would do that from multiple clients it would even be a DDOS Attack.

Give the server time to process your responses e.g. by doing only one connection at a time by e.g. firing your next request in the success or error callback of the call.